# MS Outlook- Multiple All Day Meeting Template?

Tags: outlook, calendar, ms-office

Is there a way for me to make multiple all-day events at weird intervals. If so, is there a way to make it a template so I can do it faster?

I have a very repetitive business that has identical deadlines for every project I am given. Currently, I have to add all of these deadlines into my outlook calendar manually. I'd like a short cut where I can select a template or something that automatically programs the various all-day calendar items that I currently create manually.

For instance, I get a project today and I want to make an all-day reminder in 15 days to remind me to complete my first task. 7 days later, I need an all-day reminder for my second task. 45 days later, I need a reminder for my third task.

The other scenario is deadlines. I want to add an all-day event in my outlook calendar for the final deadline for a project. I'd like a 15 day reminder and a 5 day reminder to appear on my calendar as all-day events. I know there is a way to add a single reminder, but if it pops up while I'm away from my desk, I tend to ignore the reminder. An all-day calendar item is much harder to ignore.

Is there some way to automatically do this through a macro or function of MS Outlook of which I'm unaware. I keep my life in outlook, so I'd like for all of my deadlines to appear there as well.

TIA